# Implement "oncreate" Jquery event

Tags: javascript, jquery

**Background info**

I have an image gallery with a function that runs which checks width() vs height() and scales to fill area accordingly (since max-width and max-height css properties only work up to max image dimensions)

I am struggling to find the correct jQuery event to trigger my imgResize function.

`.ready()` was my first guess but that only works when DOM is initially loaded, so the first image on DOM load scales correctly, but the rest fail after that.

**Question**

What jQuery event can I use to trigger my imgResize function when an img is dynamically loaded into DOM?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Please provide some code. Eg, what have you tried so far, what exactly is not working, ... Especially how do you load these images 'dynamically'?

Comment: You can use the [.load() event](https://api.jquery.com/load-event/) but **"(since max-width and max-height css properties only work up to max image dimmensions)"** is not realy true, at least from what I understand the question. See here: https://jsfiddle.net/3y5fetmm/

Comment: @caramba you set width and height to 100%, not max-width and max-height. As I stated before, max-height and max-width only scale up to max image dimensions. I am trying to always fill window and its either height: 100% or width: 100% based on which is larger

Comment: Yep, what I mean is don't use `max-width` and `max-height`. You could do like so: https://jsfiddle.net/3y5fetmm/1/ ?